# MongoDB Group by one field and count occurrences of field values within an array

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the below data structure per document (we are working with a test set of 1.9 million documents like this):

```
{
  "Object": {
    "Items": {
      "ItemDetail": [
        {
          "ItemNumber": 3562,
          "ItemName": "LG-ICED LATTE",
        },
        {
          "ItemNumber": 18419,
          "ItemName": "Sausage Biscuit",
        }
      ],
    },
    "Payment": {
      "PaymentHeader": {
        "CashierNumber": 23,
        "CashierName": "RVwGwYjpCsdYJg"
      },
    },
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to produce the following output as efficiently as possible:

```
{
  CashierName: "RVwGwYjpCsdYJg",
  Items: [ 
    {
      "ItemName": "Sausage Biscuit",
      "Count": 23
    },
    {
      "ItemName": "LG-ICED LATTE",
      "Count": 52
    }
  ]
}
```

This is part of a C# project I am working on where I currently generate this kind of output from the following queries but it takes a little longer than we are looking for I am trying to leverage the database to produce the output I need:

```
aggregate([{ "$project" : { "CashierNumber" : "$Object.Payment.PaymentHeader.CashierNumber", "ItemName" : "$Object.Items.ItemDetail.ItemName" } }, { "$unwind" : "$ItemName" }])
```

Or

```
aggregate([{ "$project" : { "CashierNumber" : "$Object.Payment.PaymentHeader.CashierNumber", "ItemName" : "$Object.Items.ItemDetail.ItemName" } }])
```

Which returns:

```
{
  _id: 6461fec95c6d9dcad9530a2f
  CashierNumber: 23
  ItemName: "[LG-, $ FULL FLAVOR SHOT, SF VANILLA, SKIM]"
}
```

OR

```
{
  _id: 6461fec95c6d9dcad9530a2f
  CashierNumber: 23
  ItemName: "[[LG-] [$FULL FLAVOR SHOT, SF VANILLA, SKIM]]"
}
```

which we then manipulate.

Comment: Unwind the `Object.Items.ItemDetail` array, group by `CashierName` and `ItemName`, then group by `CashierName`. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PBK3yF8HDaT)

Comment: Functionally you can get what you want via an aggregation pipeline that has an `$unwind` and then a `$group`. But it's not clear to me what the constraints "_as efficiently as possible_" and "_a little longer than we are looking for_" actually imply. Can you be more specific about those requirements?

Comment: @YongShun This is exactly what I am looking for, much appreciated.
You should post this an an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `Object.Items.ItemDetail` array into multiple documents.
2. `$group` - Group by `Object.Payment.PaymentHeader.CashierName` and `Object.Items.ItemDetail.ItemName`. And perform the count.
3. `$group` - Group by `_id.CashierName`. Add the document with the `ItemName` and `Count` fields into the `Items` array.
4. `$project` - Decorate the output document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Object.Items.ItemDetail"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "CashierName": "$Object.Payment.PaymentHeader.CashierName",
        "ItemName": "$Object.Items.ItemDetail.ItemName"
      },
      Count: {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.CashierName",
      Items: {
        $push: {
          ItemName: "$_id.ItemName",
          Count: "$Count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      CashierName: "$_id",
      Items: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PBK3yF8HDaT)